# CRM 2011 generated code using ICodeWriterFilterService fails to build

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

Using the sample code at http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html I have altered this so that GenerateEntity and GenerateOptionSet to have the code:

`return optionSetMetadata.Name.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("myprefix");`

This generates the types including some enumerations for the optionsets.  The actual implementation of the optionset in the entity doesn't use this however, but I get the following:

```
    [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("myprefix_fieldname")]
    public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue myprefix_FieldName
    {
        get
        {
            Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue optionSet = this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("myprefix_fieldname");
            if ((optionSet != null))
            {
                return ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue)(System.Enum.ToObject(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue), optionSet.Value)));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("myprefix_FieldName");
            if ((value == null))
            {
                this.SetAttributeValue("myprefix_fieldname", null);
            }
            else
            {
                this.SetAttributeValue("myprefix_fieldname", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(((int)(value))));
            }
            this.OnPropertyChanged("myprefix_FieldName");
        }
    }
```

Obviously casting the OptionSetValue to an int in the setter does not compile, I assume that it should be generating the property with a type that matches the generated enum, but isn't.  What do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: Would this solution help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8967568/1114306

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a bug in the crmsrvcutil that has since been fixed.  My code for OptionSet properties now looks like this:

```
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("prioritycode")]
public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue PriorityCode
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("prioritycode");
    }
    set
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanging("PriorityCode");
        this.SetAttributeValue("prioritycode", value);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("PriorityCode");
    }
}
```

And I get no error setting the OptionSetValue...

Comment: I'm using the latest version crmsvcutil (5.0.9690.3218) and the code generated for my OptionSet properties is still outputting in the problematic form from the original post. :/

Comment: @Polshgiant Consider adding your own question.  Writing in people's comments is likely not going to result in an answer for your particular question.

Comment: I was just noting that my experience with the latest version of crmsvcutil is different from yours. I eventually worked around the problem using a combination of answers from the post Guarav linked to above.