# How can I make CRMSvcUtil.exe generate unduplicated, error-free early-bound option sets?

Tags: enums, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I use Erik Pool's implementation of [`ICodeWriterFilterService`](http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html) and Manny Grewal's [`GenerateOption`](http://manny-grewal.blogspot.com/2011/03/generate-enum-for-option-set-picklist.html) function as a model to filter out unwanted entities in the  file that `CRMSvcUtil` generates. While Erik recommends returning `true` for the `GenerateOptionSet` method to generate `enums` for option sets, doing so duplicates any of the global option sets that are used by any particular entity (as mentioned in [one of the comments](http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html?showComment=1305152121747#c8163048116065581595) on that post).

To address this, I check to see if the option set has been already generated, and if so, I return the default option (presumably `false` for most cases) as in the below.

```cs
//list of generated option sets, instantiated in the constructor
private List<string> GeneratedOptionSets;

public bool GenerateOptionSet
    (OptionSetMetadataBase optionSetMetadata, IServiceProvider services)
{
    if (!GeneratedOptionSets.Contains(optionSetMetadata.Name))
    {
        GeneratedOptionSets.Add(optionSetMetadata.Name);
        return true;
    }

    return _defaultService.GenerateOptionSet(optionSetMetadata, services);
}
```

But when incorporating the generated file in my CRM projects, the compilation error

> ```
> Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue' to 'int'
> ```

is always thrown by every line of code that looks like

```cs
this.SetAttributeValue
    ("address1_shippingmethodcode", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(((int)(value))));
```

.

As a workaround, I use a separate project where I filter the entities I need, run `CRMSvcUtil` with the arguments Erik suggests, replace the troublesome part of the code `(int)(value)` (where `value` is an `OptionSetValue`) with `value.Value` after the file is generated, and then resave the file, and all issues go away.

My question is this: do I need to do something differently that will fix this compilation error with the default `CRMSvcUtil` generated file without doing something so hackish as altering that generated file?

Comment: JFYI. Similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443981/crm-2011-generated-code-using-icodewriterfilterservice-fails-to-build).

Comment: @paramosh: Yeah, just seeing that question now for some reason. I think I would've posted anyway because I was unclear of any consequences relating to customizing the `GenerateOptionSet` method, but anyway, hopefully Guarav's answer will yield an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm betting that Guarav's answer is the real way to go, but in the absence of documentation surrounding `CRMSvcUtil`, I'm forced to use my workaround. (I use a separate project where I filter the entities I need, run `CRMSvcUtil` with the arguments Erik suggests, replace the troublesome part of the code`(int)(value)` (where `value` is an `OptionSetValue`) with `value.Value` after the file is generated, and then resave the file.)

Not a perfect solution, but it's been working on the few samples I've worked with so far.

Comment: Since this one is marked as the solution, it is worth pointing out that this is not what the generated code is trying to implement http://stackoverflow.com/a/21771992/1465593

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ICustomizeCodeDomService` interface to rewrite the `SetAttributeValue` method for the optionSets. Snippet below:

```
namespace The.NameSpace
{
 using System;
 using System.CodeDom;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Linq;

 using Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility;
 using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;

/// <summary>
/// The customize code dom service.
/// </summary>
public sealed class CustomizeCodeDomService : ICustomizeCodeDomService
{
    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>
    ///   The metadata.
    /// </summary>
    private IOrganizationMetadata metadata;

    #endregion

    #region Properties



    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// The customize code dom.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="codeCompileUnit">
    /// The code compile unit.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="services">
    /// The services.
    /// </param>
    public void CustomizeCodeDom(CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        // Locate the namespace to use
        CodeNamespace codeNamespace = codeCompileUnit.Namespaces[0];

        var metadataProviderService = (IMetadataProviderService)services.GetService(typeof(IMetadataProviderService));
        var filterService = (ICodeWriterFilterService)services.GetService(typeof(ICodeWriterFilterService));

        this.metadata = metadataProviderService.LoadMetadata();

        foreach (EntityMetadata entityMetadata in this.metadata.Entities)
        {
            if (filterService.GenerateEntity(entityMetadata, services))
            {
                CodeTypeDeclaration entityClass =
                    codeNamespace.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().First(codeType => codeType.Name.ToUpper() == entityMetadata.SchemaName.ToUpper());

                UpdateEnumSetter(entityClass, entityMetadata);

            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private static void UpdateEnumSetter(
  CodeTypeDeclaration entityClass, EntityMetadata entity)
    {
        foreach (var attributeMetadata in entity.Attributes.Where(attributeMetadata => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributeMetadata.AttributeOf)))
        {
            //Match the respective field Name. 
            AttributeMetadata metadata1 = attributeMetadata;
            foreach (
                CodeTypeMember codeMembers in
                    entityClass.Members.Cast<CodeTypeMember>().Where(
                        codeMembers => codeMembers.Name == metadata1.SchemaName))
            {
                var codeProperty = (CodeMemberProperty)codeMembers;

                if (codeProperty.HasSet)
                {
                    if (attributeMetadata.AttributeType != null && attributeMetadata.AttributeType.Value == AttributeTypeCode.Picklist)
                    {
                        ((CodeConditionStatement)codeProperty.SetStatements[1]).FalseStatements[0] =
                            new CodeSnippetStatement
                            {
                                Value =
                                    String.Format(
                                        "this.SetAttributeValue(\"{0}\", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(value.Value));",
                                        attributeMetadata.LogicalName)
                            };
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}.{1}", entity.LogicalName, attributeMetadata.LogicalName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: I'll have a look at the documentation, but examples seem to be in short supply. Do you have sample code at hand that implements this interface?

Comment: Thanks for the sample. When running crmsvcutil against this code, though, the exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.CodeDom.Co
deExpressionStatement' to type 'System.CodeDom.CodeConditionStatement'.` is thrown, presumably by the line of code `((CodeConditionStatement)codeProperty.SetStatements[1]).FalseStatements[0] =...`. Any ideas as to the correct cast here?

Comment: +1. For reference, I had to combine this answer with user1589970's answer to get this to work.

Comment: Really the CORRECT answer would be to use this method to change the return type of the method to System.Nullable<entityname_attributename> and then update the cast in the getter rather than update the setter. Then you will never ever see the damn "OptionSetValue" class ever again.

Answer (score 4):

Some changes to the UpdateEnumSetter method:

```
    private static void UpdateEnumSetter(CodeTypeDeclaration entityClass, EntityMetadata entity)
    {
        foreach (var attributeMetadata in entity.Attributes.Where(attributeMetadata => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributeMetadata.AttributeOf)))
        {
            AttributeMetadata currentMetadata = attributeMetadata;
            foreach (CodeTypeMember codeMembers in entityClass.Members.Cast<CodeTypeMember>().Where(codeMembers => codeMembers.Name == currentMetadata.SchemaName))
            {
                CodeMemberProperty codeProperty = (CodeMemberProperty)codeMembers;
                if (codeProperty.HasSet)
                {
                    if (attributeMetadata.AttributeType != null && (attributeMetadata.AttributeType.Value == AttributeTypeCode.Picklist || attributeMetadata.AttributeType.Value == AttributeTypeCode.Status))
                    {
                        if (codeProperty.SetStatements[1].GetType() == typeof(CodeConditionStatement))
                        {
                            ((CodeConditionStatement)codeProperty.SetStatements[1]).FalseStatements[0] = new CodeSnippetStatement
                            {
                                Value = String.Format("this.SetAttributeValue(\"{0}\", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(value.Value));", attributeMetadata.LogicalName)
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            codeProperty.SetStatements[1] = new CodeSnippetStatement(String.Format("this.SetAttributeValue(\"{0}\", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(value.Value));", attributeMetadata.LogicalName));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 thanks. Combining this with Guarav's response worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this fault is to do with the code attempting to make optionsets that look like the code below when the types are available for use. Note the only difference is the correct type being chose for the return type and the cast.

It *should* be possible to update the codegen stuff to fix this bug, but it might be better to get microsoft to fix the damn thing properly, I would make a solution but I don't really have time to implement it right now because we have a mostly working solution even if we have to deal with the optionsetvalue class.

```
public enum entityname_optionsetname 
{
    Value = 200
}

[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("myprefix_fieldname")]
public entityname_optionsetname myprefix_FieldName
{
    get
    {
        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue optionSet = this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("myprefix_fieldname");
        if ((optionSet != null))
        {
            return ((entityname_optionsetname)(System.Enum.ToObject(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue), optionSet.Value)));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanging("myprefix_FieldName");
        if ((value == null))
        {
            this.SetAttributeValue("myprefix_fieldname", null);
        }
        else
        {
            this.SetAttributeValue("myprefix_fieldname", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(((int)(value))));
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("myprefix_FieldName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally am able to generate early bound class with a filtered set of entities and error free option set. I found the bulk of my answer through this thread, so thanks guys. The problem though is it's difficult to compile all of the various suggestions into something that actually... compiles. So I thought I'd post my final solution for the benefit of others, here's what worked for me.

I used Erik Pool's, Manny Grewal's, and Peter Majeed's solution for outputting only distinct enums with proper values, then combined that with Gaurav Dalal's solution (updated by JFK007 to fix the cast error) to re-write the `SetAttributeValue` that caused the `(int)(value)` error. And as an added bonus, I used the same solution for filtering distinct option sets to also filter for distinct option set values (which was an issue in my org).

The result is a class library containing `CodeWriterFilter` and `CustomizeCodeDomService`, the cmd batch file to run `CrmSvcUtil.exe`, and the `filter.xml` to filter the entities.

In your class library add references to `CrmSvcUtil.exe`, `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk`, and `System.Runtime.Serialization` then compile the dll and copy it to the same the folder as your `CrmSvcUtil.exe`. Use the command I've included to reference your new assembly and build the early bound class file.

`CodeWriterFilter`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace SvcUtilFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// CodeWriterFilter for CrmSvcUtil that reads list of entities from an xml file to
    /// determine whether or not the entity class should be generated.
    /// </summary>
    public class CodeWriterFilter : ICodeWriterFilterService
    {
        //list of entity names to generate classes for.
        private HashSet<string> _validEntities = new HashSet<string>();

        //reference to the default service.
        private ICodeWriterFilterService _defaultService = null;

        //list of generated option sets, instantiated in the constructor
        private List<string> GeneratedOptionSets;

        //list of generated options, instantiated in the constructor
        private List<string> GeneratedOptions;

        /// <summary>
        /// constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="defaultService">default implementation</param>
        public CodeWriterFilter(ICodeWriterFilterService defaultService)
        {
            this._defaultService = defaultService;
            this.GeneratedOptionSets = new List<string>();
            this.GeneratedOptions = new List<string>();
            LoadFilterData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// loads the entity filter data from the filter.xml file
        /// </summary>
        private void LoadFilterData()
        {
            XElement xml = XElement.Load("filter.xml");
            XElement entitiesElement = xml.Element("entities");
            foreach (XElement entityElement in entitiesElement.Elements("entity")) {
                _validEntities.Add(entityElement.Value.ToLowerInvariant());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// /Use filter entity list to determine if the entity class should be generated.
        /// </summary>
        public bool GenerateEntity(EntityMetadata entityMetadata, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return (_validEntities.Contains(entityMetadata.LogicalName.ToLowerInvariant()));
        }

        //All other methods just use default implementation:

        public bool GenerateAttribute(AttributeMetadata attributeMetadata, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return _defaultService.GenerateAttribute(attributeMetadata, services);
        }

        public bool GenerateOption(OptionMetadata optionMetadata, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            //return _defaultService.GenerateOption(optionMetadata, services);
            string label = optionMetadata.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label;

            //remove spaces and special characters
            label = Regex.Replace(label, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", string.Empty);
            if (label.Length > 0 && !char.IsLetter(label, 0)) {
                label = "Number_" + label;
            }
            else if (label.Length == 0) {
                label = "empty";
            }

            if (!GeneratedOptions.Exists(l=>l.Equals(label))) {
                GeneratedOptions.Add(label);
                optionMetadata.Label = new Label(label, 1033);
                return _defaultService.GenerateOption(optionMetadata, services);
            }
            else { return false; }
        }

        public bool GenerateOptionSet(OptionSetMetadataBase optionSetMetadata, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            //return _defaultService.GenerateOptionSet(optionSetMetadata, services);
            if (!GeneratedOptionSets.Contains(optionSetMetadata.Name)) {
                GeneratedOptionSets.Add(optionSetMetadata.Name);
                return true;
            }

            return _defaultService.GenerateOptionSet(optionSetMetadata, services);
        }

        public bool GenerateRelationship(RelationshipMetadataBase relationshipMetadata, EntityMetadata otherEntityMetadata, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return _defaultService.GenerateRelationship(relationshipMetadata, otherEntityMetadata, services);
        }

        public bool GenerateServiceContext(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return _defaultService.GenerateServiceContext(services);
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomizeCodeDomService`:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;

namespace SvcUtilFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The customize code dom service.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class CustomizeCodeDomService : ICustomizeCodeDomService
    {
        #region Constants and Fields

        /// <summary>
        ///   The metadata.
        /// </summary>
        private IOrganizationMetadata metadata;

        #endregion

        #region Properties



        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// The customize code dom.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="codeCompileUnit">
        /// The code compile unit.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="services">
        /// The services.
        /// </param>
        public void CustomizeCodeDom(CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            // Locate the namespace to use
            CodeNamespace codeNamespace = codeCompileUnit.Namespaces[0];

            var metadataProviderService = (IMetadataProviderService)services.GetService(typeof(IMetadataProviderService));
            var filterService = (ICodeWriterFilterService)services.GetService(typeof(ICodeWriterFilterService));

            this.metadata = metadataProviderService.LoadMetadata();

            foreach (EntityMetadata entityMetadata in this.metadata.Entities) {
                if (filterService.GenerateEntity(entityMetadata, services)) {
                    CodeTypeDeclaration entityClass =
                        codeNamespace.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().First(codeType => codeType.Name.ToUpper() == entityMetadata.SchemaName.ToUpper());

                    UpdateEnumSetter(entityClass, entityMetadata);

                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private static void UpdateEnumSetter(CodeTypeDeclaration entityClass, EntityMetadata entity)
        {
            foreach (var attributeMetadata in entity.Attributes.Where(attributeMetadata => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributeMetadata.AttributeOf))) {
                AttributeMetadata currentMetadata = attributeMetadata;
                foreach (CodeTypeMember codeMembers in entityClass.Members.Cast<CodeTypeMember>().Where(codeMembers => codeMembers.Name == currentMetadata.SchemaName)) {
                    CodeMemberProperty codeProperty = (CodeMemberProperty)codeMembers;
                    if (codeProperty.HasSet) {
                        if (attributeMetadata.AttributeType != null && (attributeMetadata.AttributeType.Value == AttributeTypeCode.Picklist || attributeMetadata.AttributeType.Value == AttributeTypeCode.Status)) {
                            if (codeProperty.SetStatements[1].GetType() == typeof(CodeConditionStatement)) {
                                ((CodeConditionStatement)codeProperty.SetStatements[1]).FalseStatements[0] = new CodeSnippetStatement {
                                    Value = String.Format("this.SetAttributeValue(\"{0}\", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(value.Value));", attributeMetadata.LogicalName)
                                };
                            }
                            else {
                                codeProperty.SetStatements[1] = new CodeSnippetStatement(String.Format("this.SetAttributeValue(\"{0}\", new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(value.Value));", attributeMetadata.LogicalName));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

`CrmSvcUtil_run.cmd` Command Batch File:

```
@echo off

set url=https://[organization].api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc

echo.
echo Generating CrmSvcUtil Proxy class in output folder
echo.

CrmSvcUtil.exe /metadataproviderservice:"MetadataProvider.IfdMetadataProviderService, 
MetadataProvider" 
/url:https://[organization].api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:Xrm.cs 
/namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext /serviceContextPrefix:Xrm 
/u:[username] /p:[password] 
/codewriterfilter:SvcUtilFilter.CodeWriterFilter,SvcUtilFilter 
/codecustomization:SvcUtilFilter.CustomizeCodeDomService,SvcUtilFilter

echo.
pause
```

filter.xml

```
<filter>
  <entities>
    <entity>systemuser</entity>
    <entity>team</entity>
    <entity>role</entity>
    <entity>businessunit</entity>
    <entity>account</entity>
    <entity>product</entity>
    <entity>transactioncurrency</entity>
  </entities>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a bug in the crmsrvcutil that has since been fixed.  My code for OptionSet properties now looks like this:

```
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("prioritycode")]
public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue PriorityCode
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("prioritycode");
    }
    set
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanging("PriorityCode");
        this.SetAttributeValue("prioritycode", value);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("PriorityCode");
    }
}
```

And I get no error setting the OptionSetValue...

Comment: I'm using the latest version crmsvcutil (5.0.9690.3218) and the code generated for my OptionSet properties is still outputting in the problematic form from the original post. :/